# How to declare a nullable local variable in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried the following statement but failed with compile error. 
     `declare @myValue int NULL`

Comment: I don't see any compile error... hint, hint

Comment: All local (scalar) variables are nullable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are trying to make the variable as `NOT NULL` variable which will not accept any `NULL` values then I don't think it is possible.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) says

> After declaration, all variables are initialized as `NULL`, unless a
>   value is provided as part of the declaration

so you don't have to mention it `explicitly`

Answer (score 23):

Your syntax is wrong. By default all variables are nullable

```
 declare @myValue int=NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 select @myValue
 NULL
```